# Scroll to the top button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a button on the bottom right corner whenever the user scroll down to the bottom of the page. I am trying to see if there is any error in Rails or Chrome Dev Tools but nothing is showing up to identify the issue.

This is how I have my **`application.tml.erb`** with the button on the bottom part before the body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Playfair+Display:400,400i" rel="stylesheet">

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main container">

    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>

    <%= yield %>

  </div><!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->

  <!-- SCROLL UP -->
  <a id="scroll-up" class="waves"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a> 
  <!-- THIS IS WHERE I ADDED THE SCROLL UP BUTTON -->

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried adding a `content_tag` but still no success:

```
<% content_tag :a, :id => "scroll-up", :class => "waves" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
<% end %>
```

**`application.js`**:

```
// SHOW/HIDE SCROLL UP
    function show_hide_scroll_top() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()/2) {
            $("#scroll-up").fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            $("#scroll-up").fadeOut(300);
        }

    }


    // SCROLL UP
    function scroll_up() {              

        $("#scroll-up").on("click", function() {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

    }

    // SHOW/HIDE SCROLL UP
    show_hide_scroll_top();


    // SCROLL UP
    scroll_up();
```

And my **`application.css.scss`**:

```
#scroll-up {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 8030;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    display: none;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #19496e;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

#scroll-up:hover {
    background-color: #94ccdf;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#scroll-up.waves .waves-ripple {
    background-color: #c6e6f1;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    #scroll-up {
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
    }

}
```

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Function calling method is not Right please Add this condition

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    show_hide_scroll_top();
    });
```

Good Luck